# Axiom of regularity definition

Tags: set-theory, axioms

I was reading about the axiom of regularity on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity).

It is stated that:

> In mathematics, the axiom of regularity (also known as the axiom of foundation) is an axiom of Zermelo–Fraenkel set theory that states that every non-empty set $A$ contains an element that is disjoint from $A$.
>
> $$\forall x\left(x\neq \emptyset\implies\exists y\in x\left(y\cap x=\emptyset\right)\right)$$

How can this be correct?

If $A$ contains an element $x$, then $x$ can not be disjoint from $A$, because $x$ belongs both to $A$ and to the set containing only $x$.

What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Your question makes no sense. Syntactically.

Comment: What does it mean that $x$ is "from" $A$, and what do you mean by "belongs"?

Comment: Are you concerned about an element being part of two or more sets at the same time? Look at this: $A=\{\{1,2\},\{2,3\},2\}$. The $2$ is element of both sets inside $A$ *and* of $A$ itself. Are you feeling uncomfortable with this?

Comment: I updated my question because I phrased it poorly.

Comment: The sets $A:=\{\varnothing\}$ and $x:=\varnothing\in A$ are disjoint. So here $x$ is an element of $A$ disjoint from $A$ (i.e. the sets have no common elements).

Comment: An element $x$ is not the same as the set $\{x\}$ containing only this element. Is this the confusing point? If $x\in A$, then $\{x\}$ must not be in $A$, so $x$ can be disjoint from $A$.

Comment: The fact that $X$ belongs both to $A$ and to the set containing only $x$ (commonly denoted by $\{x\}$) tells us $\{x\}$ can not be disjoint from $A.$ It doesn't follow that $x$ itself is disjoint from $A.$

Comment: It is better to avoid mix-and-match with variables... Regularity: $∀A \
 (A≠∅ \to ∃x∈A(x∩A=∅))$. If $A$ is not empty (this is the part $A≠∅$) it contains an element: call it $x$ (i.e. it is this is the part $∃x∈A$). What does it mean: "$x$ can not be from $A$" ? We have assumed that $A$ is not empty and we have called $x$ (one of) the element(s) of $A$.

Comment: If for instance we have `A = {1, 2, 3}`, can we say that `1` is disjoint from `A`?

Comment: Depends on how $1$ is (and the other numbers are) defined as a set, but usually it is set $1:=\{\varnothing\}$, so yes, they are disjoint.

Comment: @octavian That depends on how $1$ is defined.

Comment: @M.Winter yes that's what I have trouble with, the difference between `x` being disjoint from `A` and `{x}` being disjoint from `A`.

Comment: You are misunderstanding the fact that $x \in x$. This is not... The empty set is... empty, i.e. it has **no** elements. Thus, $x \notin \emptyset$, for every $x$, and also $\emptyset \notin \emptyset$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA but the axiom is about non-empty sets, right?

Comment: @octavian At the moment it is not completely clear to me what confuses you about the distinction between $x$ and $\{x\}$. Maybe you can edit your question to make this clear.

Comment: Thus, in general, it is not true that $x \in x$... The axiom asserts that this is so for every $x$. Apply the axiom to $A= \{ x \}$. We have that $x \in \{ x \}$ and thus $\{ x \}$ is not empty. Thus $∃y∈ \{ x \} (y∩ \{ x \} =∅))$. But $\{ x \}$ has only one element: $x$; thus $x ∩ \{ x \} =∅$. Conclusion: $x \notin x$ (otherwise, form: $x \in x$ and $x \in \{ x \}$ we get $x ∩ \{ x \} = x$).

Answer (score 4):

One consequence of this is that $x \cap \{x\} = \emptyset$. This often confuses people, because it seems counter-intuitive.

But if the sets $x$ and $\{x\}$ have a common element, it must be $x$ itself, since $x$ is the *only* element of $\{x\}$. And this would lead us to conclude (reluctantly) that $x \in x$. Such a set would have "no foundation", since we'd have to "keep opening up" the set $x$ only to find still *another* one inside it: $x\in x \in x \in x\dots$

To avoid this, we devised a formula that says (in effect) "the buck stops somewhere". At first, it was believed we might need the set-equivalent of "atomic elements", or *ur-elements*, primitive objects that *belonged* to sets, but were not sets themselves. But mathematicians being what they are, found that set theory "made sense" without using ur-elements, and so they by and large abandoned them (why pack more luggage than you need?).